# What is a good way to check if an observable is completed

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, rx-java

I was wondering if there is a convenient method to check if an observable has been completed. For instance I have a test

```
test("An observable that tracks another observable is completed")
{
      val sub = PublishSubject[Boolean](false)
      val newOb = sub recovered // This methods returns an Observable[Try[T]] 


      val res = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[Try[Boolean]]()
      val cr = newOb subscribe( v => res += v, t => assert( false, "There shouldn't be an exception" ), () => println("Stream Completed") )
      sub.onNext(true)
      sub.onNext(false)
      sub.onNext(true)
      sub.onCompleted
      assert( res.toList === List(Success(true), Success(false), Success(true) ))
      newOb.isEmpty subscribe { v => assert( v == true, "Stream should be completed" ) }
  }
```

The `recovered` method returns an Observable[Try[T]] and is an extension to the standard Observable. I want to check that the Observable[Try[T]] is completed when the source Observable is completed.

So I wrote a test with a Subject to which I Publish a few values and then eventually complete. Is there a simple way I can check to see that newOb is also completed? There is no method like isCompleted in Observable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the essence of the pattern Observer, when there is a call onCompleted, the appropriate handler is triggered, and only it can be understood that the Observer completed. But I have heard that if the Observer has been completed and it is attached to the handler, it works immediately, but I think it has already been implemented at a lower level where asJavaObserver.

That link may help:
[Netflix RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/blob/master/language-adaptors/rxjava-scala/src/main/scala/rx/lang/scala/Observer.scala)